# How to setup an association to conditionally load the lastest record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to setup an association to conditionally load the last record. Ex. User.include(latest_post: [:monkey]). Scope does not work since I am trying to eager load the association. I was wondering how this could be done in Rails 4. I am trying to set this up to eager load the latest post for every user. I tried using .last or an inner query with where but it errors out when include tries to inject a list of user id's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So two thoughts here.

1.) `current_user.posts.last` is not an n+1 query so you don't need to eager load there.

2.)  If you're not scoping users to only see their own posts, you could do :

`User.includes(:posts).order(created_at: :desc).limit(User.count)`

That will do the eager loading for `user` and `posts`, order by most recent and then just grab one for each user.

Output looks something like:

```
2.1.1 :009 > User.includes(:posts).order(created_at: :desc).limit(User.count)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 100
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN (100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: the second answer grabs every posts belonging to the user, i just want the latest post, hence the reason for the conditional assocation

Comment: It grabs the last post for each user.  Isn't that what you're asking for?

Comment: woah, if Andy and Bob post a post, then Charles posts three posts, then grabbing the latest three posts limit(3) won't get the latest post of each user, it will just get Charles' three posts as they are most recent, right? That is what the code looks like